# Wiring a switch to an outlet to control Garbage disposal

Tags: wiring, disposal

I have a gfs outlet with the power coming to it.Can i install a swith next to it to go to a outlet under my sink to power the garbage disposal

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Can I use a receptacle and switch for a dishwasher and garbage disposal?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/36051/2196)

Comment: No. But an Electrician surely could.

Answer (score 1):

NO. You CANNOT power a disposal from an existing **kitchen counter** receptacle circuit.

If the dishwasher is on a 20A circuit typically you can share that circuit, other than that usually they are on a dedicated circuit.